# How do I draw a simple stickman with javascript?

Tags: javascript, drawing

```
     function setup(){

      a = 5;
    }

    function draw(){
      background(0,0,0);


      if (a == 5)
      {
        fill(255,255,255);
        ellipse(250,150,100,100);

        fill(255,255,255);
        rect(245,199,10,160);

        fill(255,255,255);
        rect(150,199,200,10);
}
    if (a == 6)
  {
    fill(250,189,65);
    ellipse(250,250,100,100);

     fill(178,102,255);
    ellipse(250,250,500,100);
  }
}

function keyTyped()
  {
    a = 5;
  }
  if (key == 'f')
  {
    a = 6;
  }
}
```

^
Above is the javascript (sketch.js), HTML is just

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
  <body>




  </body>
</html>
```

This is what I have so far, and it's just showing the head, arms and body, i can't find a way to make diagonal lines / or an arc for the legs

edit: i just pasted the full code- I'm looking to find the simplest approach to creating an arched line?

Comment: your code is incomplete

Comment: Post full code html and javascript

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this:

```
 function setup(){

  createCanvas(500,500);

  // initialize a, assign the value 5 to a
  a = 5;
}

function draw(){
  background(0,0,0);

  fill(255,255,255);
  text("M for Stickman, F for Flower",10,30);

  if (a == 5)
  {


    ellipseMode (CENTER);

ellipse (150,60,50,50);
point (140,60);
point (160,60);

rectMode (CENTER);

rect (150,135,50,100);

line (125,85,100,160);
line (175,85,200,160);
line (130,185,130,250);
line (130,250,125,250);
line (170,185,170,250);
line (170,250,175,250);
}
```

> https://www.openprocessing.org/sketch/34624#

Comment: hey, do you mind explaining the lines of code? (rectMode, elliposeMode) I'm pretty new to this stuff.

Comment: how do i also use ellipseMode to create a flower? As in, an ellipse inside another ellipse?

Comment: Here you have: http://processingjs.org/reference/ellipseMode_/
This explains how ellipseMode is used